# Simple DB to maintain one view?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, nosql, key-value-store

I have a python program in which I am downloading user data and updating a table.  I only need to store the most current updates for each user.

Is there a simple (maybe No SQL, key/value) DB that would be good for maintaining a single table like this?  I would just store it in a dict in python but I need persistence.

I am running this on an AWS EC2 linux server.  I know there are AWS options (Dynamo) but I thought a local DB might be easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look into python stdblib [dbm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html) module, fallback to an embedded [okvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okvs).